# Iam trying to install a new module in odoo but error occuring, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to use the ODOO server, however I am getting this exception. Seems like a configuraton issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'**
```

Odoo Server Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 684, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 360, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 913, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 532, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1368, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1356, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/api.py", line 396, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-71>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 73, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 474, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 592, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 453, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 346, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 197, in load_module_graph
    registry.setup_models(cr)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 269, in setup_models
    model._setup_base()
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/models.py", line 2780, in _setup_base
    self._add_field(name, field.new())
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/models.py", line 402, in _add_field
    field.setup_base(self, name)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/fields.py", line 278, in setup_base
    self._setup_attrs(model, name)
  File "/home/ajay/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-14.0/odoo/fields.py", line 2282, in _setup_attrs
    ondelete.setdefault(key, 'set null')
Exception
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: which python version are you using?